# Utilizing Switching Mirrors in a Quantum Eraser to Send Binary Information Back in Time

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time, quantum-eraser

[image]

[image]

We know that the information that reaches the detectors in a quantum eraser cannot be used to send information back in time, but I'm thinking there is still a way.

When viewing the results of the quantum eraser, what you are really seeing in the clump vs interference pattern on the shortest-path detector is weather or not the wave/particle passed through the scrambling mirror, or was reflected by it. If the wave/particle passes through, we see a clump pattern on the shortest-path detector. If the wave/particle reflects, we see an interference pattern on the shortest-path detector.

A new invention allows for a pane of switching mirror to be turned reflective or transparent with an electrical signal, meaning we can now use the reflectivity of the mirrors as the signal source.

If a particle passes through the switchable mirror, the information is retained, meaning the shortest-path detector measures a particle (0). If a particle is reflected by the switchable mirror, the information is destroyed, and the shortest-path detector measures an interference (1).

By reading if the shortest-path detector has a clump or interference pattern, we can assign a binary bit to the result.

T=0
Fire laser thru double slit, entangle photons, record if sensor reads clump (0) or interference pattern (1).

T=1
Light delay - mirrors, increase distance, different materials, etc...

T=2
Signal initiation - send data signal to mirrors, changing between transparent (0) and reflective (1).

T=3
Quantum eraser either destroys or retains information based on signal initiation. Signal data of interference (1) and clump (0) converted to binary and read at T=0.

End result: a signal sent back in time, by the amount of time that the light is delayed through the light delay device at T=2.

PROVE ME WRONG

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to PSE!

I think the issue you'll find is in this statement being incorrect:

> If a particle passes through the switchable mirror, the information is retained, meaning the shortest-path detector measures a particle (0). If a particle is reflected by the switchable mirror, the information is destroyed, and the shortest-path detector measures an interference (1).

In the Quantum Eraser, what you're calling the shortest-path detector never observes "a particle **or** interference".   100% of the time it observes the absence of an interference pattern.

An interference pattern can only be *reconstructed* from a subset of the particle detection data set at the shortest-path detector by performing post-selection. For this to work, you need to have the result of detection (or lack thereof) of both entangled particles.

It is possible to construct a QE setup where you can use the detection at the shortest-path detector to have high confidence in eliminating one possible path for the sister particle, but it tells you nothing about whether the particle retains which-way information or has it erased at a later time.

See my answer here for a relevant example:  [Do "delayed choice" experiments send information back in time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/507308/do-delayed-choice-experiments-send-information-back-in-time/507355#507355)

Comment: I understand that a single-photon quantum eraser requires reconstruction from the detection data, but I'm also aware of quantum erasers using just simple polarizing filters, like the one in this video. https://youtu.be/NAsFtJ0s2XE

Comment: @Tyler You can use polarizers or whatever you’d like, but the basic mechanics remain the same - you’ll find you’re unable to determine whether which-way information was obtained by your “delayed choice” intervention until after the event has occurred, and a correlation has been made with the position eigenstate of the idler particle detector.

Comment: @Tyler If you have any doubts about this, just look at the overlap in the nodes of the resulting interference pattern with the which-way band of idler detection hits.   A single location (x,y) on the idler plate could be consistent with either a which-way detection, or find itself in a band for one of the no-path detectors for the entangled partners.   There is no way to tell which one of those cases you are in until you’ve got the entangled detection to compare.